# Apple TV subtitles

Tags: appletv, subtitle, movie

How can I find out if (and what languages) subtitles are included in Apple TV movies before i buy it?

Comment: When you buy a movie on iTunes, is there any difference if you buy it via an AppleTV or not?

Comment: Probably not. Is there a way to find it out in iTunes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this for translation or closed-captioning purposes? The languages a movie supports should be listed in iTunes, and all of the movies *should* (but might not) have closed-captioning for those with disabilities.

Comment: I'm non native English speaker, so it helps me to understand the spoken text better if i can read it as well. That's what I need it for.